# Vuejs multiple active buttons

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a list where every list item contains a button and i want a user to be able to click multiple button. I'm generating my list like so:

```
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <button type="button">{{item.title}}</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

but the problem with my code is whenever a user click a button, it turns the rest of the buttons to "unclicked". been trying to play with the `focus` and `active` stats but even with just css i cant get to enable multiple select .
i did manage to change the look of the current selected button:

```
button:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #6acddf;
  color: #fff;
}
```

any idea how can i allow multiple buttons to be clicked?

to make things  a bit clearer, i am going to create an AJAX call later and pass the `item.id` of each item where it's button is clicked

Comment: Add another object to the `item`, like `isClicked` where is `false` by default. An then on your click method, like `clicked`, set the value to true and append some class with some styles.

Comment: was hoping not to get this answer. i would much rather avoid changing the data structure if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would much rather avoid changing the data structure if possible

Well you have to store somewhere that you clicked on the *clicked* `item`.

If you can't edit the `items` array then you can always create a new one, like `isClicked` where you store those values.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'foo'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'bar'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'baz'
      }
    ],
    isClicked: []
  },
  beforeMount() {
    // set all values to false
    this.items.forEach((item, index) => this.$set(this.isClicked, index, false))
  },
  methods: {
    clicked(index) {
      // toggle the active class
      this.$set(this.isClicked, index, !this.isClicked[index])
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <button @click="clicked(index)" :class="{'active': isClicked[index]}">{{item.title}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for storing those values.

---

**However** you can just use Vues event to manipulate the `classList` property, like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-for="i in items" @click="e => e.target.classList.toggle('active')">{{ i }}</button>
</div>
```

But it doesn't *feel* right, IMHO.

Also you can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store those states. So it's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use id attribute for list items to make it unique.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :id="item.id">
        <button type="button" @click="doThis">{{item.title}}</button>
    </li>
</ul>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {
      doThis() { 
          // Use this to access current object
      }
  }
});
```